# nginx nodejs load balance sharing information

Tags: node.js, nginx, load-balancing

I would like to use nginx to load balance between multiple instance of my node app running on different ports.  What I wanted to know - is it possible that the different instances running on different ports can communicate with each other.  For example if I have a chat on one instance can people communicate with another instance of my app running on a different port because of load balance? If so how? and if not how can I make that work.
I greatly greatly appreciate your help on this.

Comment: If you are using AWS or similar web services, I think you can.

Comment: You would have to have a shared backend between your instances that would support some form of message passing e.g. redis pubsub.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have two groups of solutions here *(notice that in the second approach there is no sharing information, you just balance the load in "smarter" way)*:

1. On application level. You have to configure your application or node.js (i don't know if node support it other application server's does) in order to have access on a shared backend as @cejast mentioned in the comment. You have several approaches to accomplish that, in all of them the goal is every instance of your application, no matter where it is, to have access to all the users live information.
2. With load balancing method. You can solve this by a specific method of load balancing nginx supports ip_hash (see [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/) for ip_has and other load balancing methods nginx supports.)
   With ip_hash nginx will send the same ip (/24 subnet actually) always to the same instance so you won't worry that an instance will have to handle a session that doesn't know.

In case you will follow the load balancing method to solve your problem I suggest to learn exactly how it works since in some occasions might not fit your needs.

For example nginx `ip_hash` that i mentioned earlier creates a hash that is uses for stickiness from first 3 octets from an IPv4, that means if your application get most of its traffic from a specific class C subnet load balancing won't balance that good. You should use `remote_addr` variable in that case.

This is a nice reference for [nginx load balancing](https://www.nginx.com/blog/choosing-nginx-plus-load-balancing-techniques/).